# How can I offset the view position for a step in impress.js

Tags: impress.js

I am using impress.js to build a presentation.  I have several steps arranged around a central image (a diagram).  I can successfully position the steps around the image using data-x and data-y but when the presentation is 'on' each step, I want to offset the view so that you can see more of the central image.

How do I offset the presentation view for each step?

Answer (score 1):

This question would be easier to answer if you had provided some specific code example. That said, I do understand what you're doing. You can position your step contents in multiple ways, all via CSS:

- Set the slide `width` and `height` to values less than your screen. This will leave a margin outside the slide contents where your background / other image is visible.
- Use `margin` or `padding` to do the same.
- Use e.g `text-align` to flow the contents to one side, away from the image

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a margin on the step to move it around.